# isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, connection, wifi-direct

I try to transfer data between phones via wifi-direct and my code works fine everyfirst time I run through it. However, after I close all the sockets in both client and server and try to connect the socket again, it gives me this Exception. Also, after I lock the screen of the server phone and unlock it, I can built up the connection once again. Can someone familar with socket give me any advice?
This shouldn't be about wrong IP address/port right?

CODE for Client phone

```js
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_SEND_FILE)) {
            if(!socket.isConnected())
            {
                String host = intent.getExtras().getString(
                        EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS);
                int port = intent.getExtras().getInt(EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT);
                try {
                    socket.bind(null);
                    InetSocketAddress MyAddress = new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
                    socket.connect(MyAddress, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                }
            }
                try{
         /*returns an output stream to write data into this socket*/
                    OutputStream stream = socket.getOutputStream();
                    String count = String.valueOf(_count);
                    stream.write(count.getBytes());                  
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {

                    if (socket.isConnected()) {

                        try {
                            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                            socket.shutdownOutput(); // Sends the 'FIN' on the network
                            while (is.read() >= 0) ; // "read()" returns '-1' when the 'FIN' is reached
                            socket.close();
                        }

                        catch (IOException e) {
                            // Give up
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

CODE for Server phone

```js
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8888);
            Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
            InputStream inputstream = client.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            int i;
            while ((i = inputstream.read()) != -1) {
                baos.write(i);
            }
            String str = baos.toString();
            client.shutdownOutput(); // Sends the 'FIN' on the network
            while (inputstream.read() >= 0) ; // "read()" returns '-1' when the 'FIN' is reached
            client.close(); // Now we can close the Socket
            serverSocket.close();
            return str;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: "*after I close all the sockets in both client and server*": If you as well closed the listing socket on the server you obviously cannot connect to the server any more. `ECONNREFUSED` means the client's connection request reached a host, but the host refused to allow the client to connect, as nothing is listening on the port requested.

Comment: @alk So, should I do anything on the server side like closing my InputStream? Should I keep both ServerSocket and Socket on serverside intact?

Comment: @alk Is it because that my server class extends AsyncTask which means it only can execute once?